# Prevent SMTP Connections From Outside Localhost

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, smtp, postfix, iptables

I have a web site which needs to send email to confirm orders and alert subscribed users of certain events. I do **not** need to send email through the server for any other reason, so I would like to prevent anyone outside of localhost from even connecting to port 25 for SMTP. I've tried to do this like so:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0 --dport 25 -j DROP
```

but I can still telnet to port 25 and type SMTP commands from another computer. What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a better way to achieve what I want? To clarify: what I want is a machine that can send emails (via SMTP), but only ones that originate from scripts running on the machine. And any configuration must "live" through re-boots.

I'm using Postfix on Ubuntu (Hardy).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that a better solution, if you don't want to be able to receive emails from outside, is to tell postfix that exactly, in the `master.cf` file replacing :

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

which is usually the first non comment line, but your mileage may vary depending on wether the postfix you have is modified by your vendor, with :

```
127.0.0.1:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Comment: +1 Fixing the problem not the symptoms.  Much better than using iptables to block the ports.

Comment: REMINDER: SMTP is the "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol". It's for both sending _and receiving_. I broke my mail server six days ago because I forgot/didn't fully understand this. A good reminder to check you understand the question before applying the solution. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't want the `-s 0.0.0.0` clause.  You're only denying access from the 0.0.0.0 address.

You probably need something like:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.0/8 --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

This will accept any incoming connection from the localhost (i.e. from the loopback range - 127.0.0.1-127.255.255.255) and drop all others.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. But is there a way to get it to persist through server reboots? A config file to edit somewhere? (`sudo find /etc -name iptables` gives me nothing.)

Comment: You want to install a /etc/init.d/iptables script, and set up a /var/lib/iptables/active file with your rules. See http://www.5dollarwhitebox.org/wiki/index.php/Howtos_Basic_IPTables